# How to emulate .users.get in Python class?

Tags: python, class, methods, substitution, getattr

I want to create a fictive micro-class with attributes .users.get and no having implementation of them inside of the class (I'm planning to use this class as a substitude in MagicMock(spec=This_Class)). I've read about getattr but I've no idea how to implement it right. Maybe you could me to figure it out?

```
class A(object):
  def __getattr__(self, attr):
    if attr == 'users':
        self.__getattr__(self.users, 'get')
    if attr == 'get':
        return [{'uid': 4444444}]
```

Comment: I see that you have already accepted an answer. But I still haven't fully understood your question (I hadn't understand the "call" until I read your comment in the accepted answer). And you want to use MagicMock, or avoid it? What is `This_Class`? What is `A`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__getattr__` will only be called if `users` has not been found. Since you apparently have a `self.users` it will be found and returned.

`__getattribute__` will be called (almost always) and will allow you to intercept the returned value.

The best approach imho:

```
class A(object):

    def __getattribute__(self, attrname):
        try:
            attr = object.__getattribute__(self, attrname)
        except AttributeError as e:
            raise e

        if attrname == 'users':
            attr = attr.get()

        return attr
```

Edit according to the comment:

```
class A(object):

    def __getattr__(self, attrname):
        if attrname == 'users':
            return self

        if attrname == 'get'
            return self

        raise AttributeError('{} not found'.format(attrname))

    def __call__(self)
        return [{'uid': 4444444}]
```

An attribute cannot return the `list` you want, because you want to **invoke** the attribute. That means you have to return `self` and then `self` will be invoked as if it were the `get` method of `users` and will return the `list` (with the embedded `dict` in it)

Comment: I'd like to add that I want to call it later this way: mocked_object.users.get()[0]['uid']

Comment: And where has the attr.get() been implemented?

Comment: I think the comments do not match the question. if that's how you want to call the `users` you don't need `__getattr__` or `__getattribute__` at all. Your attribute `users` will be returned and this attribute will **have** a `get` method. Else the solution is to return the instance. Let me add a 2nd option